# How to make a floating clouds effect in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Im new to jetpack compose and android development, how would one create this floating cloud effect in jetpack compose.

This is the code from my current attempt that does not work at all:

```
data class CloudProperties(val offset: Offset, val frameHeightRatio: Float)

@Composable
fun CloudShape(color: Color, modifier: Modifier) {
    AbsoluteRoundedCornerShape(1f)
}

@Composable
fun Cloud(
    properties: CloudProperties,
    move: Boolean,
    rotationStart: Float,
    duration: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color
) {
    val rotation by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (move) rotationStart else rotationStart + 360,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(tween(durationMillis = duration), RepeatMode.Restart)
    )

    CloudShape(
        color = color,
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset(properties.offset.x.dp, properties.offset.y.dp)
            .graphicsLayer(rotationZ = rotation)
            .then(modifier)
    )
}

@Composable
fun FloatingClouds(
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.DarkGray,
    cloudColor: Color = Color.LightGray
) {

    val bottomTrailingProps = remember { CloudProperties(offset = Offset(0.0f, 0.0f), frameHeightRatio = 1.2f) }
    val topTrailingProps = remember { CloudProperties(offset = Offset(0.0f, 0.0f), frameHeightRatio = 0.9f) }
    val bottomLeadingProps = remember { CloudProperties(offset = Offset(0.0f, 0.0f), frameHeightRatio = 1.0f) }
    val topLeadingProps = remember { CloudProperties(offset = Offset(0.0f, 0.0f), frameHeightRatio = 1.1f) }

    val moveState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backgroundColor)
    ) {
        Cloud(
            properties = bottomTrailingProps,
            move = moveState.value,
            rotationStart = 0.0f,
            duration = 2,
            color = randomColor(),
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
        )

        Cloud(
            properties = topTrailingProps,
            move = moveState.value,
            rotationStart = 240.0f,
            duration = 1,
            color = randomColor(),
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd)
        )

        Cloud(
            properties = bottomLeadingProps,
            move = moveState.value,
            rotationStart = 120.0f,
            duration = 5,
            color = randomColor(),
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart)
        )

        Cloud(
            properties = topLeadingProps,
            move = moveState.value,
            rotationStart = 180.0f,
            duration = 3,
            color = randomColor(),
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart)
        )
    }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        moveState.value = true
        onDispose { /* cleanup code if needed */ }
    }
}

@Composable
fun randomColor(): Color {
    val random = Random.Default

    // Generate random RGB values between 0 and 255.
    val red = random.nextInt(256)
    val green = random.nextInt(256)
    val blue = random.nextInt(256)

    // Create and return a Color object using the random RGB values.
    return Color(red = red, green = green, blue = blue)
}
```

Source of what I am trying to recreate using SwiftUI: [Floating Cloud Effect](https://www.cephalopod.studio/blog/swiftui-aurora-background-animation)

As stated I am new to android developement and don't know what could be going wrong in the code above to be causing it not be working like the article above.